# Concatenate N number of csv files to one single csv file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a requirement to build a shell script which would concatenate all available CSV files into one. All these CSV files have a similar structure (i.e same headers and number of columns) and these files have a common prefix `GFP`.

for example : One day I might have the following files ,

```
GFP_20210609.csv
GFP_20210610.csv
```

or sometimes I might have many such files. The problem here is I am not sure how many such files would appear in a day (assuming not greater than 5 CSV files per day).

Am quite a beginner to shell scripting. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
sed 1d GFP_20210610.csv > GFP_20210610_NO_HEADER.csv
cat GFP_20210609.csv GFP_20210610_NO_HEADER.csv > GFP_FINAL.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `awk`

```
awk 'NR==1||FNR>1' GFP*.csv > output.csv
```

This will print all lines of each file starting from the second line (`FNR>1` means per-file line-counter larger than one) to suppress repeating headers, but be sure to print the very first line encountered (`NR==1`) which is the header line of the first file.

The output is then redirected to a file `output.csv`.

The syntax makes use of the fact that `awk` will print the current line if a condition found outside of a rule block (`{ ...}`) is true. In this case, we can omit the rule blocks altogether since we don't actually want to edit, but only filter, the input files.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we'll create our header file once and we'll leave it in the same folder as the rest of csv files

```
head -qn 1 GFP_20210609.csv > common.header
```

**common_header.csv** contains the 1st line of any csv file you choose (based on what you've said, all csv files have the same header). You should build this file once and leave it for further use in the same directory.

`head` command outputs first *n* lines of a text file, which is "1" in our header file case.

`tail` command outputs last *n* lines of a text file. Starting at "1" we will be ignoring first line on all csv files, as we want to avoid header repetition.

Extra  **-q** (quiet) parameter in both `head` and `tail` prevents extra output information we don't want in final file.

Next line is source code for your script:

```
cat common.header > FINAL.csv && tail -qn 1 GFP_*.csv >> FINAL.csv
```

Both commands `cat` and `tail` are jointed with a `&&` which means that  `tail` will run *only* if `cat` command succeed.

(*) Note: `tail -qn 1...` could also be written as `tail -q -n 1...` and is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` we explicitly close the filehandle at each eof condition, this is to reset the line counter. For the absolute first line we use any scalar variable $nr and preincrement it.

```
perl -lne 'print if
  ++$nr==1||$.>1;
  eof && close(ARGV);
' GFP_*.CSV > total.csv
```

---

Using `GNU sed` with the `-s` separated streams option which treats files individually.

```
{
head -n 1 "$(printf '%s\n' GFP_*.CSV |head -n 1 -)"
sed -se 1d GFP_*.csv
} > total.csv
```